# JQuery/CSS - Different <body> background images based on value, without loading in document.ready() on _Layout page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# MVC Web Application that is used by multiple departments. I decided to take a break from the heavy stuff and mess around with something a bit more laid back. When a user accesses the site I check our database for their information, one of which is a department ID that I store in a Session["DeptId"] variable.

I am able to get the background images to change based on this Session["DeptId"] value but I'm currently doing it in the shared "_Layout.cshtml" page within the $(document).ready() function which is causing the background to load just slightly after the page comes up, resulting in a flashing on each page load. Of course, if I just set the background in the body to a single image within my css page, this flashing doesn't happen. Is there anyway to get this to work prior to the document being ready first to avoid the slight delay?

_Layout.cshtml JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (@Convert.ToInt32(Session["DeptId"]) == 3) {
        $('body').addClass("husky");
    }
    else {
        $('body').addClass("stopLight");
    }
});
```

CSS classes:

```
.stopLight {
    background-image: url("Images/StopLightBackground.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
}

.husky {
    background-image: url("Images/HuskyBackground.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ofcourse you can do that directly in the body tag in your `_Layout.cshtml` like:

```
<body class="@(Session["DeptId"] == "3" ? "husky" : "stopLight")">
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, always nice to see a different take on how to solve the same problem. As far as performance, it appears to behave similarly. The page still loads and then a split second later the image appears. It is negligible and I'm probably worrying about it for no reason. By the way you have a syntax error, the second ? needs to be a :, I tried to edit it but it's under peer review. :)

Comment: You might as well just go with `Session["DeptId"]) == "3"` and not worry about the ToInt32 - you don't care if it's *not* 3 but the ToInt32 *will* care if it's not a number.

Comment: This will be the fastest method and is *exactly* the same as writing it directly in the `<body class=...` directly in the .cshtml.   The delay will be caused elsewhere.  It could be that your image is too large so taking time to download (and cache off).  Or it could be that your `<link rel=` css is at the bottom of the page instead of in the `<head>`.    The only faster method would be to use `<body style='background-image:url("@(... ? "Images/StopLightBackground.jpg" : ."...")'>` so it's not waiting on the css.